# fail2ban 404 bruteforcing sharex

Tags: brute-force, fail2ban

I use my own server (nginx, I use https://yunohost.org as a CP) as a screenshot uploader with ShareX (https://getsharex.com/).
During the upload process of the screenshots the filenames are randomized.

The problem:
Recently many people have been coding bruteforcers for these image uploading sites.
They just write a small program that sends random httprequest to the url and check if it returns 404 and if not it saves the url.
These people could gain access to semi-private screenshots they're not supposed to see.

The solution:
These programs don't use any proxies, so you should be able to block these requests with fail2ban.
I don't have any experience with it so I can't do it myself so I'm asking you.

I need a fail2ban regex and jail that blocks IP's of too many requests that result with error 404 (for example if someone sends 5 requests per second (404!), it bans them).

I hope anyone can help me.

Best regards
KNIF

Comment: See also this repo: https://github.com/mariusv/nginx-badbot-blocker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For details see the article
[How to setup Fail2ban to detect Apache 404 attacks?](https://bobcares.com/blog/fail2ban-apache-404/)

To summarize:

**1. Create fail2ban filter**

Create the file `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-404.conf` containing:

```
failregex = ^<HOST> - .* "(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*" 404 .*$
ignoreregex =.*(robots.txt|favicon.ico|jpg|png)
```

- **failregex** identifies IP addresses that make too many 404 requests
- **ignoreregex** excludes the valid files such as `robots.txt`, `favicon.io`
  and images.

**2. Create a custom jail**

Add the following code in the file `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`:

```
[apache-404]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = apache-404
logpath = /var/log/httpd/error_log
logpath = /var/log/httpd/access_log
bantime = 3600
findtime = 600
maxretry = 5
```

- **logpath** specifies the apache log file
- **bantime** species how many seconds an offending IP is banned
- **maxretry** specifies the total number of connection attempts.

So, if a client makes more than `maxretry` retry attempts within the time
specified in `findtime`, they will be banned.

See also the post
[Mitigating 404 bomb with Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/911008/mitigating-404-bomb-with-nginx).